# Dynamically change incoming call ringtone

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, ringtone, android-audiomanager

I am trying to dynamically replace my ringtone with a synthesized speech from text. But as soon as I get an incoming call my app seems to loose audio focus and I cannot change my ringtone dynamically.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

~Saurabh

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the bug in my code.

I was calling a Receiver for my incoming calls. I was creating the `texttospeech` object in my `onReceive()` function instead of my Receive class constructor.

I don't know why but when I make this change it works.